# Kotlin, How do I make a function for distinctBy method

Tags: kotlin

Suppose, I have this list which contains a list of employee info.

```
val distinctEmployee = employees.distinctBy { it.firstName }
```

I want to make a function and pass as a parameter for distinctBy method so I can apply any kind of distinct method to the list. I expect something like this.

```
val highSalaryEmployee = employees.filterBy(salaryFilter)

function salaryFilter(employee: Employee): Boolean {
  return employee.salary > 350000
}
```

I have done this with filterBy method before, but I dont know how to apply with distictBy method.

Edit:
So this what I actually have tried and still got stuck.

```
val distinctEmployee = employees.distinctBy { firstNameDistinct(it) }

function firstNameDistinct(employee: Employee): Boolean {
  return employee. // what should be returned here?
}
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused about what your concern is here. As far as I'm aware it should be the same, you just need a function that will return a Boolean based on the value of any term for employees.

Comment: @MarcoKurepa yes, but I don't know what value I should compare with since I only have 1 parameter let's say employee. what if I want to distinctBy firstName should I return employee.firstName?, but that is a string not a boolean which makes me really confused.

Comment: As far as predicate-calculus is concerned, `distinctBy(...)` is the same thing as `groupBy(...).single(...)` - which means that given 2 or more objects sharing the same key-value you need to decide which 1 of those 2 will be picked - which you haven't told us. Granted, you _could_ use `.first()` but that would give you potentially non-deterministic results, so I don't think that's a good idea.

Comment: @Patrick Uhm... are you sure `distinctBy` is even what you should be using? What end-result are you after, exactly?

Comment: @Dai I will try writing what I have tried wait a minute

Comment: @Dai Ok, please take a look at edit section. I don't know what should be returned there if I want to distinctBy the firstname

Comment: The code you've posted is nonsensical: `distinctBy` is a reduction (aggregation) that uses a key-selector callback and always retrieves _the first_ item in each group - but that's not what you want because it means discarding potentially useful data - so let me ask you this: if your `employees` list consists of `[ { firstName: "Bob", lastName: "Smith" }, { firstName: "Bob", lastName: "Jones" }, { firstName: "David", lastName: "Davidson" }, { firstName: "David", lastName: "Foobar" } ]` then what output are you expecting?

Comment: I would expect [ { firstName: "Bob", lastName: "Smith" }, { firstName: "David", lastName: "Davidson" }]

Comment: @Patrick Okay, but _why_ should Bob Jones and David Foobar be discarded? Why should Bob Smith's data be preserved?

Comment: Just to make it distinct and it also depends on how the customer would want. So I want to create several functions and pass it as a parameter rather than hard-coded style.

Comment: It can be firstname distinct, salary distinct etc..

Comment: Answering your question directly, you just need to return first name from `firstNameDistinct()`. But honestly, I don't see how this is better than simple `distinctBy { it.firstName }`. The logic is still hardcoded in both cases, whether you use `firstName` property or `firstNameDistinct()` function.

Comment: @broot Exxxxxacccctly what I want thanks!. So actually I want to have this method with generic type and force the developer to implement this function with their concrete type.

Comment: `distinctBy` already takes a generic selector function though! Its signature is `(T) -> K`, where `T` is the type the collection contains, and `K` is the type of the key you're returning for each item, so `distinctBy` can compare them. It might help if you say what problem you're actually facing here - like your `salaryFilter` one works fine, it returns the first employee with a salary over that amount, and the first less than or equal to it. But apparently that's not what you want?

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little confused by what you are trying to do. If you could clarify, we can find an answer. But, I'll answer with some assumptions.

First, I think there is some confusion about what `distinctBy` does. From the [Kotlin docs](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/distinct-by.html):

> Returns a list containing only elements from the given array having distinct keys returned by the given selector function.

So, let's look at this code as an example:

```kotlin
fun test() {
    val employees = listOf(
        Employee("Bob", 75000),
        Employee("Jenna", 400000),
        Employee("Mark", 120000),
        Employee("Rebecca", 80000),
        Employee("Tanner", 30000),
        Employee("Bob", 45000)
    )
    
    val distinctEmployees = employees.distinctBy { it.name }
    distinctEmployees.forEach {
        println(it)
    }
}

class Employee(val name: String, val salary: Int) {
    override fun toString(): String = "Name: $name\tSalary: $salary"
}
```

This will be the output:

```
Name: Bob   Salary: 75000
Name: Jenna Salary: 400000
Name: Mark  Salary: 120000
Name: Rebecca   Salary: 80000
Name: Tanner    Salary: 30000
```

Notice it is a list, not just one employee - and Bob is only shown once even though there were originally two Bobs. Basically `employees.distinctBy { it.name }` is saying, "Give me a list of all the employees in this list, but only unique names, get rid of any employees with duplicate names."

Now comes the assumption - since you are using the name of `employee`, singular - I am assuming you don't want a list, but you want to grab an employee out of that list with a given name. To achieve this, you could do something like:

```kotlin
val employee = employees.firstOrNull { it.name == "Bob" }
```

But know that if there are multiple Bobs, you will only get one and it might be the "wrong" one depending on what you are doing with it. You could also do:

```kotlin
val filteredEmployees = employees.filter { it.name == "Bob" }
```

But that would get you a list:

```
Name: Bob   Salary: 75000
Name: Bob   Salary: 45000
```

So you could also do:

```kotlin
val employee = employees.firstOrNull { it.name == "Bob" && it.salary == 75000 }
```

But again, you could still run into a situation where two employees have the same name and same salary. I would suggest adding some kind of unique ID to the employee, and just doing `firstOrNull` on that:

```kotlin
fun test() {
    val employees = listOf(
        Employee("1234", "Bob", 75000),
        Employee("5678", "Jenna", 400000),
        Employee("9123", "Mark", 120000),
        Employee("4567", "Rebecca", 80000),
        Employee("8912", "Tanner", 30000),
        Employee("3456", "Bob", 45000)
    )
    
    // val employee = employees.filter { it.name == "Bob" }
    val employee = employees.firstOrNull { it.employeeID == "3456" }
    println(employee)
}

class Employee(val employeeID: String, val name: String, val salary: Int) {
    override fun toString(): String = "Name: $name\tSalary: $salary"
}
```

Output:

```
Name: Bob   Salary: 45000
```